# How to check what Job sent the email in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Do you have any T-SQL script for check which Job able/sending email?

My problem: I setup a job for sending a reminder, after it i modified the Job to send a query result.

Today I got the Reminder and Query result too :) I think something is stucked.

Thanks

Comment: If it solves your problem : - you can open the JOB and check the alert and notification properties of it and make sure you have properly configured those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking the [`dbo.sysjobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobs-transact-sql) system table for this purpose like

```
select job_id,
       name,
       notify_level_eventlog,
       notify_level_email
       from msdb..sysjobs
where enabled = 1
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot that another Job exists with "Reminder" name :)